# Is this an exact differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is the next equation an exact differential equation?
$$\cos \theta \, dr - (r\sin \theta-e^\theta) \, d\theta=0$$

What I have:

$$\frac{\partial(\cos \theta)}{\partial\theta} = -\sin\theta$$
and
$$\frac{\partial(-r\sin\theta)}{\partial r} = -\sin\theta$$
I'm not sure about the last one I guess I can take $-\sin\theta$ as a constant and I just need to differentiate the r but do you know if my results are good?

Comment: @avid19 Sorry I corrected it, can you help me please

Comment: It seems like you've already done the work.. Those partials are equal, so you may conclude that the DE is indeed exact.

Comment: @ImATurtle Than you!, I don't know why the downvotes, is this way too easy to be asked?

Comment: The essential definition of "exact" is that it is a differential of some function.  Thus: $d(r\cos\theta+e^\theta)$ $= \cos\theta\,dr -(r\sin\theta-e^\theta)\,d\theta$. Infinitely small changes in $r$ and $\theta$ result in a certain infinitely small change in $r\cos\theta+e^\theta$, and the differential tells you the exact size of those changes. ${}\qquad{}$